# Encrypting web.config section using aspnet_regiis removes system.webServer element

Tags: iis, encryption

I am using the following command to encrypt a custom section in my web.config:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe\aspnet_regiis.exe -pe CustomSection -site  sitename -app /
```

This properly encrypts the specified section, however it also removes the `system.webServer` element located within the `location` element from the web.config, leaving root `system.webServer` alone.  I'd rather it did not remove this element.

How can I encrypt the section without removing the `system.webServer` element?

Comment: This may be a bug in IIS, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562572/settings-from-system-webserver-sometimes-removed-from-web-config-file